# How do i web scrape elements of a page that only appear when using a certain chrome extension?

Tags: python, web-scraping

for example if i go to

https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/MP7%20%7C%20Whiteout%20%28Field-Tested%29

and i use the chrome extension "CSGOfloat market checker" , it automatically shows me the float, a string of numbers under every listing which i can find in inspect element.

if i use python to access the site the float isn't there obviously because it doesnt have an extension when accessing the site. is there a way to get over this?

Comment: You can use selenium to load the extension, then use beautiful soup to get the float value.

Comment: What is the expected output? And what have you tried?

Comment: ill try using selenium to load the extension. just started to learn web scraping so don't really know what to try, thanks!

Comment: when i use selenium to load the extension, is there an alternative to driver.page_source()? i found that it gives you the page source which does not include the html that the extension adds to the page which i can find when i manually inspect element